# how save file on server using HostingEnvironment.MapPath()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, server.mappath

in this code iam trying to save text document on server / wwwroot folder. nothing happens :(!

if i am working on localhost and doing the same routine like this, everything works fine and i can save text document on local pc.:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same code works in your Dev machine and not working in Production, It should be folder Permission issue. I guess you have to change the folder permissions in server so that ASP.NET can write to that directory.

Checkout [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/Deployment-to-a-Hosting-Provider-Setting-Folder-Permissions-6-of-12) link which explains how to do that.

Make sure you are not giving Write/Modify Permission to "**Everyone**"

Comment: how to do that? hard-coding again?

Comment: @RagimsRagimovs: Check the link in my answer